# What is org.glassfish.jersey.core

Tags: rest, glassfish, jersey, jersey-2.0

To create REST web services, I usually just use `com.sun.jersey`; but now, I keep seeing `org.glassfish.jersey.core` as well.  So, I was wondering what is `org.glassfish.jersey.core`?  Is this another implementation of JAX-RS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `com.sun.jersey` packages are Jersey 1.x (which is included in Glassfish 3.x).

The `org.glassfish.jersey.core` packages are Jersey 2.x (which is included in Glassfish 4.x).

You shouldn't mix both versions in a web application.

Comment: Just to confirm; so, I can consider com.sun.jersey old/obsolete, and just use org.glassfish.jersey.core in my new rest applications.